# How can I use Javascript and Python together (Javascript executes a python function based on certain input)?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have a simple speech recogniser running in Javascript, which detects my voice and converts it into text. However, I want it to do certain commands such as open a folder on my laptop, which is possible to do in python,  but I do not know how to call a python function from javascript based on the command given.

I have tried to use speech recognition in python and it worked, but the speech recognition API in Javascript is much faster, so that is the reason I want to use Javascript for the speech recognition, and python for performing other tasks not possible (at least not with ease) with Javascript.

Thanks,
Adi

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Sorry for the late response, but what do you mean by recognition time? If you mean how fast it can convert speech to text, it takes roughly 1.5 seconds using JavaScript. In python it takes 3 sometimes 4 seconds, which is quite slow compared to JavaScript. Btw I'm using a library called Speech Recognition in python